# Change space around section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting

I am trying to modify Jake's resume (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs).

I wish to place the "TECHNICAL SKILLS" section after the education section; however, this results in uneven spacing above the section heading of "TECHNICAL SKILLS" and after the last item "Libraries:  pandas, NumPy, Matplotlib".

Is it possible to modify this to make the spacing even both before and after? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Jake Ryan} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small 123-456-7890 $|$ \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{jake@su.edu}} $|$ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/jake}} $|$
    \href{https://github.com/...}{\underline{github.com/jake}}
\end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      {Bachelor of Arts in Computer Science, Minor in Business}{Aug. 2018 -- May 2021}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Blinn College}{Bryan, TX}
      {Associate's in Liberal Arts}{Aug. 2014 -- May 2018}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%
%----------PROGRAMMING SKILLS----------
\section{Technical Skills}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: Java, Python, C/C++, SQL (Postgres), JavaScript, HTML/CSS, R} \\
     \textbf{Frameworks}{: React, Node.js, Flask, JUnit, WordPress, Material-UI, FastAPI} \\
     \textbf{Developer Tools}{: Git, Docker, TravisCI, Google Cloud Platform, VS Code, Visual Studio, PyCharm, IntelliJ, Eclipse} \\
     \textbf{Libraries}{: pandas, NumPy, Matplotlib}
    }}
 \end{itemize}
 
%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Undergraduate Research Assistant}{June 2020 -- Present}
      {Texas A\&M University}{College Station, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}
        \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data}
        \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
      \resumeItemListEnd
      
% ----------Multiple Positions Heading----------
%    \resumeSubSubheading
%     {Software Engineer I}{Oct 2014 - Sep 2016}
%     \resumeItemListStart
%        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
%          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines}
%     \resumeItemListEnd
%    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
%------------------------------------------

    \resumeSubheading
      {Information Technology Support Specialist}{Sep. 2018 -- Present}
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Communicate with managers to set up campus computers used on campus}
        \resumeItem{Assess and troubleshoot computer problems brought by students, faculty and staff}
        \resumeItem{Maintain upkeep of computers, classroom equipment, and 200 printers across campus}
    \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Artificial Intelligence Research Assistant}{May 2019 -- July 2019}
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Explored methods to generate video game dungeons based off of \emph{The Legend of Zelda}}
        \resumeItem{Developed a game in Java to test the generated dungeons}
        \resumeItem{Contributed 50K+ lines of code to an established codebase via Git}
        \resumeItem{Conducted  a human subject study to determine which video game dungeon generation technique is enjoyable}
        \resumeItem{Wrote an 8-page paper and gave multiple presentations on-campus}
        \resumeItem{Presented virtually to the World Conference on Computational Intelligence}
      \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%----------PROJECTS----------
\section{Projects}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{Gitlytics} $|$ \emph{Python, Flask, React, PostgreSQL, Docker}}{June 2020 -- Present}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using with Flask serving a REST API with React as the frontend}
            \resumeItem{Implemented GitHub OAuth to get data from user’s repositories}
            \resumeItem{Visualized GitHub data to show collaboration}
            \resumeItem{Used Celery and Redis for asynchronous tasks}
          \resumeItemListEnd
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{Simple Paintball} $|$ \emph{Spigot API, Java, Maven, TravisCI, Git}}{May 2018 -- May 2020}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed a Minecraft server plugin to entertain kids during free time for a previous job}
            \resumeItem{Published plugin to websites gaining 2K+ downloads and an average 4.5/5-star review}
            \resumeItem{Implemented continuous delivery using TravisCI to build the plugin upon new a release}
            \resumeItem{Collaborated with Minecraft server administrators to suggest features and get feedback about the plugin}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\addvspace{20pt}` after `\resumeSubHeadingListEnd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use `\titlespacing` instead of planting negative spacings in `\titleformat`.

```
% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\scshape\raggedright\large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {}
  [\color{black}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {6pt}
  {3pt}
```

Adjust the values to suit.

I also made several changes to the code in order to avoid all other `\vspace` commands. It's easier to say

```
nosep,itemsep=3pt
```

instead of trying manually to kill spaces. I also loaded `geometry` rather than relying on manual settings of the page parameters. Again, adjust the values.

I also changed all `0.97\textwidth` declarations to `\linewidth`.

Instead of loading `fancyhdr` to get no header and footer, just use `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Finally, there were some `\small` declarations that affected *all* text. Remember that `\small` is not a command taking an argument, but it affects all text after it (respecting grouping, though).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% better
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% should be last
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{empty}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\scshape\raggedright\large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {}
  [\color{black}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {6pt}
  {3pt}

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{\item #1}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item\hfill
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,itemsep=3pt,leftmargin=0.15in,label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,itemsep=3pt]}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Jake Ryan} \\[1pt]
    \small 123-456-7890 $|$ \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{jake@su.edu}} $|$ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/jake}} $|$
    \href{https://github.com/...}{\underline{github.com/jake}}
\end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      {Bachelor of Arts in Computer Science, Minor in Business}{Aug. 2018 -- May 2021}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Blinn College}{Bryan, TX}
      {Associate's in Liberal Arts}{Aug. 2014 -- May 2018}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%
%----------PROGRAMMING SKILLS----------
\section{Technical Skills}
 \begin{itemize}[nosep,itemsep=3pt,leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \item
     \textbf{Languages}{: Java, Python, C/C++, SQL (Postgres), JavaScript, HTML/CSS, R} \\
     \textbf{Frameworks}{: React, Node.js, Flask, JUnit, WordPress, Material-UI, FastAPI} \\
     \textbf{Developer Tools}{: Git, Docker, TravisCI, Google Cloud Platform, VS Code, Visual Studio, PyCharm, IntelliJ, Eclipse} \\
     \textbf{Libraries}{: pandas, NumPy, Matplotlib}
 \end{itemize}
 
%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Undergraduate Research Assistant}{June 2020 -- Present}
      {Texas A\&M University}{College Station, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}
        \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data}
        \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
      \resumeItemListEnd
      
% ----------Multiple Positions Heading----------
%    \resumeSubSubheading
%     {Software Engineer I}{Oct 2014 - Sep 2016}
%     \resumeItemListStart
%        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
%          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines}
%     \resumeItemListEnd
%    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
%------------------------------------------

    \resumeSubheading
      {Information Technology Support Specialist}{Sep. 2018 -- Present}
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Communicate with managers to set up campus computers used on campus}
        \resumeItem{Assess and troubleshoot computer problems brought by students, faculty and staff}
        \resumeItem{Maintain upkeep of computers, classroom equipment, and 200 printers across campus}
    \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Artificial Intelligence Research Assistant}{May 2019 -- July 2019}
      {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Explored methods to generate video game dungeons based off of \emph{The Legend of Zelda}}
        \resumeItem{Developed a game in Java to test the generated dungeons}
        \resumeItem{Contributed 50K+ lines of code to an established codebase via Git}
        \resumeItem{Conducted  a human subject study to determine which video game dungeon generation technique is enjoyable}
        \resumeItem{Wrote an 8-page paper and gave multiple presentations on-campus}
        \resumeItem{Presented virtually to the World Conference on Computational Intelligence}
      \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%----------PROJECTS----------
\section{Projects}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{Gitlytics} $|$ \emph{Python, Flask, React, PostgreSQL, Docker}}{June 2020 -- Present}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using with Flask serving a REST API with React as the frontend}
            \resumeItem{Implemented GitHub OAuth to get data from user’s repositories}
            \resumeItem{Visualized GitHub data to show collaboration}
            \resumeItem{Used Celery and Redis for asynchronous tasks}
          \resumeItemListEnd
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{Simple Paintball} $|$ \emph{Spigot API, Java, Maven, TravisCI, Git}}{May 2018 -- May 2020}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed a Minecraft server plugin to entertain kids during free time for a previous job}
            \resumeItem{Published plugin to websites gaining 2K+ downloads and an average 4.5/5-star review}
            \resumeItem{Implemented continuous delivery using TravisCI to build the plugin upon new a release}
            \resumeItem{Collaborated with Minecraft server administrators to suggest features and get feedback about the plugin}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]